# What is the determinant line bundle over the solid Klein bottle?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

I have come across this object in my study, and I am wondering if it is a ‘familiar’ 4-manifold. For example, what would a Kirby diagram be for this manifold?

For some reason, I think this thing is orientable…

Comment: For some reason [I think this thing is a 3-manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_Klein_bottle).

Comment: What reason is that? It is a 1-dimensional bundle over a 3-dimensional space. For example, a determinant line bundle over an orientable 3-manifold $M$ can be identified with $[-1,1]\times M$.

Comment: The fact that Wikipedia agreed with me should be a tip-off that maybe you have something wrong. Where did you get the idea that the Klein bottle is 3-dimensional? It is a well-known 2D surface, formed by gluing together the opposite sides of a square, with one pair of opposite sides being given a twist before the gluing.

Comment: I’m talking about a solid Klein bottle. Its boundary is a Klein bottle.

Comment: Read the first line of the article you linked me. It’s a 3-manifold. THEN I want to find some properties about the 1 dimensional bundle over the 3-dimensional space. 1+3=4.